# Postgres User-defined functions: self-joins in SQL

Tags: postgresql, self-join

I have the following SQL that works just fine in psql:

```
SELECT
   parent.relname, child.relname       AS child
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent            ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child             ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
WHERE parent.relname='table_name';
```

Problem is that when I put this inside the create function block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(tablename text)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$$


  SELECT
   parent.relname, child.relname       AS child
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent            ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child             ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
WHERE parent.relname= tablename;



$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR:  schema "parent" does not exist
LINE 10:     parent.relname
```

,

When I tried "public.parent.relname", the error I am getting is:

```
ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: 

    public.parent.relname
    LINE 10:     public.parent.relname
```

How do I handle this situation properly, what is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several errors in example you provided. I took your example, and several things jumped write out:

- Return type not declared (it can be record, table, custom type,...)
- Language name not declared (plpgsql, sql, c,...)
- ...

Take a look at a [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createfunction.html), there you can find more on how to create a function in PostgreSQL, and also there are a lot of examples out there(google, stackoverflow, blog posts).

The working example that worked for me, based on your example (also depending on return type, language name):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS 
$$ 
SELECT
    parent.relname, child.relname       AS child
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent            ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child             ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
WHERE parent.relname='table_name';
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function (tablename text)
RETURNS TEXT AS
$$
DECLARE
  ret text := '';

BEGIN

SELECT
    parent.relname, child.relname

FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent            ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child             ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
WHERE parent.relname= tablename;



RETURN ret;


END;


$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

since language had to be "plpgsql" BEGIN/END block was required